# Python instances/Django

Tags: python, django

Say I want to print all my installed apps their version info on server startup.. I have this setup:

```
Project
    /app-one
        __init__.py
        otherstuff
    /app-two
        __init__.py
        otherstuff
    /__init__.py
    /admin.py
    /urls.py
    /settings.py
```

main **init** file

```
import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
     for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
         try:
             import app
             print getattr(app, '__version__', None)
         except Exception:
             pass
```

app **init** file(s)

```
__version_info__ = ('0', '0', '1')
__version__ = '.'.join(__version_info__)
```

I get into the pass statement.. I suppose this is because the way instances work in Python, but how would I fix it?

this works though:

```
import app
getattr(app, '__version__', None)
```

This fixed it:

```
import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        app = __import__(app)
        print getattr(app, '__version__', None)
```

Comment: Try adding print statements to make sure app init is running first.

Comment: at least remove exception handling to see what the error is

Comment: ImportError: No module named app... Seems you cannot import a variable thats not known until runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app` in your loop is not a module but a string. To load module by name you have to use `django.utils.importlib.import_module` function:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.importlib import import_module

for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    app_module = import_module(app)
    print getattr(app_module, '__version__', None)
```

Comment: I hadn't seen this before - is this preferred?  Looking at the code, it seems to not do too much other than call `__import__`.  I notice that it comes from [Python 2.7's importlib](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/importlib.html) - is this recommended just to help transition from Python <2.7 to Python 3?

Comment: `import_module()` is preffered if you need to access to imported module. There is a small caveat when a module is loaded from a package using `__import__`. Read the messages at http://bugs.python.org/issue9254

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing - `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` is a tuple of strings.  The `import` statement cannot do anything with that.  To do this, you need to use the [`__import__()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__).